# Highcharts: how do I add full data to multiple series in a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

This is a question similar to one (Highcharts parsed drilldown not showing on page but does in console) but is trying to do things slightly different (that one works (thanks Pawel/Salman), so I'm asking as a new question).  I am creating a column chart with multiple series with drilldown.  The data comes from a CSV file (the jsFiddle uses a mockup, thanks to Pawel on how to do that).

I need the series set up as in the Highcharts API with [name: x, data[{name: Y, y: Z, drilldown: id}]].  The problem I have is that the series appears in the log as a correct series of arrays with the data in the format required, but the data is not being pushed to the actual series[].  I have modified code below and it is in the jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/49jLf4xo/1/.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
   chart: {
          type: 'column',
          events: {
          load: function () {

              var csvData = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
              var lines = csvData.split('\n');
              var drilldown = {
                      series: []
                };
                var seriesData = [];
                   $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {

                       if (lineNo > 0 && lineNo < 4) {
                               var items = line.split(',');
                               var seriesname = String(items[0]); // this is the area name
                               var area_cost = parseFloat(items[1]); // area rollup
                               var drill_id = String(items[2]); // id of the drilldown
                               var shift_one_value = parseFloat(items[3]); // drilldown shift1 value
                               var shift_two_value = parseFloat(items[4]); // drilldown shift2 value

                      if (!isNaN(area_cost) && !isNaN(shift_one_value) && !isNaN(shift_two_value)) {

                                        seriesData.push({
                                            name: seriesname,
                                            data: ({
                                                name: seriesname,
                                                y: area_cost,
                                                drilldown: drill_id
                                            })
                                        });

                                        drilldown.series.push({
                                            id: drill_id,
                                            data: [
                                                ["shift1", shift_one_value],
                                                ["shift2", shift_two_value]
                                            ]
                                        });
                                    }
                                }

                            });

                            drilldown = drilldown;
                            series = [seriesData];
                            console.log(series);
                    }
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'My Title Here'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value Here'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        colorByPoint: true
                    }
                },

                series: [],

                drilldown: {
                    drillUpButton: {
                        relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                        position: {
                            y: 0,
                            x: 0
                        },
                        theme: {
                            fill: 'white',
                            'stroke-width': 1,
                            stroke: 'silver',
                            r: 0,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    fill: '#bada55'
                                },
                                select: {
                                    stroke: '#039',
                                    fill: '#bada55'
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    allowPointDrilldown: false,
                    activeAxisLabelStyle: {
                        textDecoration: 'underline',
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    },
                    activeDataLabelStyle: {
                        textDecoration: 'none',
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Where the data is of the format

```
<div id="data">AREA,VALUE,TYPE,SHIFT1,SHIFT2
    Blog1,50000,Blog1_Shift,5,6
    Blog2,60000,Blog2_Shift,2,3
    Blog3,40000,Blog3_Shift,7,8
</div>
```

I don't have enough rep to post an image of the console, but it looks like this:
I don't have enough rep to post an image of the console, but the "series" looks like the data below.

```
Overall it shows:
[object Array]  [Array[3]]
  0
  1
  2
```

Where the first (0) expands like this:

```
[object Array]                      [Array[3]]
  0                                 [object Array][...]
    0                               [object Object] {...}
      [functions]
        __proto__                   [object Object] {...}
        data                        [object Object] {...}
           [functions]
           __proto__                [object Object] {...}
           drilldown                "Blog1_Shift"
           name                     "Blog1"
           y                        50000
         name                       "Blog1"
```

It is the same for the other 2 arrays.

I am getting nothing but the title on the screen, nothing else shows up.

I have tried putting in .addSeries, as well as a few things from somewhat similar posts and those got me no further  Does someone have an idea where I am going wrong with this?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Div` with data doesn't look like properly formatted. Data of series must by an array, not an object. Series in load event is an array with array of arrays - loose top array nesting as it is not needed (e.g. use `series = seriesData;` instead of `series = [seriesData];`). Where are you adding series to chart? Drilldown series are also not added. Looks like it would be better to load and parse data first and then create chart with data set in specified chart's options structure.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqmjwb8z/

Comment: Thanks Kacper.  Unfortunately this does not meet the needs.  Each column should drill down to its own data.  So clicking on column Blog1, which is at 50000 would drill down to 'blog1_shift' which has two columns (one at 5 and one at 6).  Going back up, you click on Blog2, which drills down to 'blog2_shift.'  The problem I have is wanting to expand to multiple columns in a series.  To do that I need to send the seriesname, and the data name, y, drilldown id.  I think you've gotten closer though, as perhaps I need to see "series array" in the log, which I am not seeing.

Comment: So you want to set allowPointDrilldown to true (default setting)? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqmjwb8z/1/